# Quasiconformal extensions of diffeomorphisms

Tags: complex-geometry, teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

Let $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an increasing diffeomorphism. Then it is well known that there exist quasiconformal mappings of the upper half plane which extends $\gamma$. One way to construct such an extension is the Beurling-Ahlfors extension.

My question is: what other methods are there for the construction of such an extension? What I would like to do is to construct an extension $f:\mathbb H\to\mathbb H$ such that the partial derivatives of the corresponding Beltrami coeffient $\mu$ have certain values on the boundary. (Here $\mu$ is the coefficient that arises in the Beltrami equation $\partial_{\overline z}f=\mu(z)\partial_zf$.) Does anyone know any general methods for the latter question?

Answer (score 3):

```
 As far as I know, a refined version of the Beurling-Ahlfors extension
```

is constructed in the folloiwng paper:

```
 Kovalev, Leonid V.; Onninen, Jani An N-dimensional version of
```

the Beurling-Ahlfors extension. Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Math. 36 (2011), no. 1, 321–329.

```
 The principal difference is that Beurling-Ahlfors extesion is a linear extension of
```

$f$, while in Leonid and Jani's paper, they essentially use the idea of heat flow. But the problem is that it is easy to estimate the distortion via Beurling-Ahlfors extension, but very difficult to estimate the distortion via the heat flow extesion, even though the later is better. There is another extension, called Douady-Earle Extension, which essnetially says that if a quasisymmetric mapping commutes with a Fuchsian group, then then the extension can be chosen to be so as well and they have important application in Teichmuller theory, Kleinian groups and dynamics.